# Creating a custom widget using django for use on external sites

Tags: javascript, python, django, widget

I have a new site that I am putting together and part of it has statistics for the site's users. I would like to create a widget that others can use on another website by invoking javascript that reads data from my server and shows that statistics for a given user, but I am having a hard time finding specific tutorials that covers this in django.

I have seen the link at Alex Maradon's site [0], but it looks to me like that is passing html back to the widget and I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this using something like xml.

Are there any django apps for doing this or does anyone know of good how-tos?

[0] http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not matter of Django, you can solve this by using the most common solution. Javascript.

Give your users this to put on their websites.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/widget/user/124546465"></script>
```

On a django view, render the next template:

```
(function(){
document.write('<div class="mysite-userprofile">');
document.write('My visits are {{total_visits}}<br />') 
document.write('</div>') })()
)
```

So on your view, you may have something like this, the mimetype is important

```
def total_visits(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id = user_id)
    total_visits = Visits.objects.filter(user:user).total_visits() #this is a method to count, you may have to write your own logic
    context = {'total_visits': total_visits}
    render_to_response('widget_total_visits.html', context, mimetype='text/javascript')
```

What can you do next?

User settings, like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      mysite_options = {
         'just_friends': True,
         'theme': 'bluemarine,
         'realtime': True
      }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/widget/user/124546465"></script>
```

So on your template, you can use the variables set before include the script on the web site of your user, a simple stuff.

Later, you can use POST method, to gather information from the user clients. For stats.

And of course make it Ajax!

I hope this give you a path to follow

Comment: I wan to add, that you can set by javascript css styles, meanwhile the user is free of styling the widget. Win-Win

Answer (score 3):

Obey the one rule: Keep It Simple Silly!

I know it may be very web 1.0 but an iframe really is your best friend in this situation. A simple piece of code such as `<script>document.write("<iframe src='yoursite.com/userwidget/" + username + "' height='30' width='150' />");</script>` to inject an iframe at load time will save you a crapload of time writing jsonp async code and dom manipulators and making sure that all the elements you inject onto their page will be styled correctly on every different website *and* worrying about origin policies.

if you have your code plug in an iframe pointed at you page then:

- The origin is you! you don't have to worry about it.
- You can use django templates instead of js to construct the widget being shown.
- their CSS won't mess with your presentation.
- their js can't easily manipulate your stats ;)
- This is exactly what iframes were designed to do.